# Grouping/GROUP BY With LINQ in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by

I am new in MVC. In this page; I list the projects belonging to the "unit name" by loop. And what I want to do: I want to group projects belonging to the same "unit name". Each project has a "unit name" to which it belongs. There can be more than one project belonging to one unit. So I want to group it.

My cshtml code is as follows:

```
@if (Model.Projects.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Projects.ToList())
    {
        <div class="ProjectPartialBody" data-id="@item.ID">
            <div class="portlet box blue">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> @item.tbl_Unit.Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tools">
                        <a href="#" class="collapse"> </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Project", new {ID=item.ID })" class="btn btn-circle default">Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-file"></i> @item.Name</span>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"> Contract Start and End Dates: @(item.ContractStartDate != null ? item.ContractStartDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : "-") / @(item.ContractEndDate != null ? item.ContractEndDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : "-")</i></span>
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Cash Completion Rate: %@item.CashCompletionRate</label>
                            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: @(item.CashCompletionRate)%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Physical Completion Rate: %@item.PhysicalCompletionRate</label>
                            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: @(item.PhysicalCompletionRate)%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

And the view of the page is as follows (my view is in Turkish language but you'll understand what I am talking about):

[My Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE5g8.png)

Can you please help me? And if there is any other code block you want to insert, please tell me.

Comment: Each project has a "unit name" to which it belongs. There can be more than one project belonging to one unit. So I want to group it. @Paaz

Answer (score 0):

You first need to group by in your for statement:

```
foreach(var unitGroup in Model.Projects.GroupBy(g => g.tbl_Unit.Name))
{
   //...your MVC markup here
}
```

Now you actualy need to change the markup as you would need to put in another foreach loop that would generate markup for projects.

So something simillar to this.

```
<div class="ProjectPartialBody" data-id="@item.ID">
<div class="portlet box blue">
    <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption">
            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> @item.tbl_Unit.Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tools">
            <a href="#" class="collapse"> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Project", new {ID=item.ID })" class="btn btn-circle default">Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach(var project in unitGroup.ToList())
    {
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <span><i class="fa fa-file"></i> @project.Name</span>
            <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"> Contract Start and End Dates: @(project.ContractStartDate != null ? project.ContractStartDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : "-") / @(project.ContractEndDate != null ? project.ContractEndDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : "-")</i></span>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Cash Completion Rate: %@project.CashCompletionRate</label>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: @(project.CashCompletionRate)%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Physical Completion Rate: %@project.PhysicalCompletionRate</label>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: @(project.PhysicalCompletionRate)%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

There should be some errors here as I am not very familliar with your model but this should be the general idea behind it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. I'll try it.